# how to make this custom animation by changing background position in jquery using intervals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, setinterval

I am trying to make a small animation by moving the background position (frames) of the image which is background on my div. I am using Jquery to make this animation happen. I have 6 frames on the background image, first frame starting at 0,0px, second starting at 85px,0, third at 172px,0 and so on.
I want to transition between these frames until stop is clicked. My jquery code is pasted below. I have made an array for the pixels to move across. I want each frame to hold upto 1000 milliseconds, then transition to next frame. I am going wrong somewhere but unable to figure out where..
here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer;
    $("#clickMe").click(function() {
        //alert("you are here");
        timer=setInterval(moveframe,1000);
    });
    $("#stop").click(function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
    });
});

function moveframe() {
    var framespx=[0,85,172,256,512,1024];
    for (var i=0;i<framespx.length;i++) {
        alert("you ar here");
        var xPos=framespx[i]+"px ";
        var yPos="0px";
        $('.fixed').css({backgroundPosition: xPos+yPos});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code looks like has some logical error,run your code ,just can see the same background.

try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer;
    $("#clickMe").click(function() {
    //alert("you are here");
        timer=setInterval(moveframe,1000);
    });
    $("#stop").click(function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
    });
});
var j=0;
function moveframe() {
    var framespx=[0,85,172,256,512,1024];
    for (var i=0;i<framespx.length;i++) {
        if (j%framespx.length == i){
            alert("you ar here");
            var xPos=framespx[i]+"px ";
            var yPos="0px";
            $('.fixed').css({backgroundPosition: xPos+yPos});
            j++
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. can you comment why you `break` after you increment `j++`, which means everytime you enter loop, you come out of it. and why you do `j%framespx.length == i` check?..btw, your code does the right animation, I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

```
 css({'background-position': xPos+' '+yPos});
```

okay the above attribute value is a bit confusing for me, hopefully that is correct but with more surety;

```
css('background-position-x', xPos);
css('background-position-y', yPos);
```

Now I don't think `for` loop is mandatory here

```
var posAry=[0,85,172,256,512,1024];
var currPos=0;
var timer;
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#start").click(function() {       
      timer=setInterval(move,1000);        
   });
   $("#stop").click(function() {
     clearInterval(timer);
   });
});


function move() {  
  $('.fixed').css({'margin-left': posAry[currPos]+'px' }); /**you can change it to background postion/padding/... as needed by you**/
  currPos++;
  if(currPos==(posAry.length))
    currPos=0; // for looping back
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7PvwN/1/

Comment: Its not the problem with setting css property, that works fine, when i tried to change. Its getting the animation working is the issue here